# MS Access 2010 report using two different tables

Tags: sql, report, ms-access-2010

[image]

[image]

I am trying to display total of each stock with their description in a report. I have got 2 queries but do not know how to combine them. First query

```
SELECT 
  stock_partno, SUM(stock_qty) AS TotalStock
FROM 
  stock
GROUP BY 
  stock_partno;
```

Second query

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
  Stock.stock_PartNo, parts.parts_Desc
FROM 
  parts 
INNER JOIN 
  stock 
ON 
  parts.Parts_partno = Stock.stock_PartNo;
```

How do I combine both these queries so that they can display a report with total stock of each Part with their description?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able to select the `parts_Desc` column, add it to the GROUP BY clause.  That will maintain the same grouping as in the first query (because each part number has just one description).

```
SELECT  
  SUM(stock.stock_qty) AS TotalStock,
  Stock.stock_PartNo, parts.parts_Desc
FROM 
  parts 
INNER JOIN 
  stock 
ON 
  parts.Parts_partno = Stock.stock_PartNo;
GROUP BY 
  Stock.stock_partno, parts.parts_Desc;
```

Comment: Thanks for a prompt reply Dbaseman, may the god of wishes grant all yours :) hehehe